# PHP dynamic methods in constructor

Tags: php, class

I want to be able to create methods within `__construct`

I tried using lambda in the following way

```
// This is what I am trying to achieve as an end result
class A extends Z{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public function myfunc() { // do something }
}


// This was an attempt to implement it
class A extends Z{
    public function __construct() {
        //example
        if ($something_is_true) {
            $this->myfunc = function () {}
        }
        parent::__construct()
    }
}
```

I hope this explains what I am trying to achieve

**EDIT**

I have URLs mapped to functions, and I want to have some logic to determine what URL-mapped-functions exist on the class

Comment: I have URLs mapped to functions, I don't want all subclasses of A to have every single mapped URL created

Comment: But if you want to define it in the constructor as a function to be over-ridden, what would be the difference between trying to define it there instead of normally?  I think that I understand the question, just not the point.

Comment: It wouldn't be a function to be overriden, there would be logic to determine if it should be created in the first place....

Comment: Oooh, ok.  I apologize, that didn't seem to be apparent.  The answer here so far seems like it would be a good solution for you then.  However, because of how PHP works, it would all be loaded in to memory regardless.

Comment: Yeah, I should have made that clearer :) I come from a python background where you can use meta-classes. But that method should be ok despite being loaded in memory. thanks for the interest and your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think that's possible. But another way to dynamically 'create' methods within a class is to use the magic [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method.

With this method implemented, any attempt to call a non-existent method on an object will call the __call() method instead. The first parameter passed in will be the name of the function that the user called, and the second parameter will be the arguments.

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Once a class has been defined, you can't add new methods to it using standard PHP. I'd advise using __call as well but you can also accomplish what you want, if you're ok with using variable variables, by creating the function contents dynamically with create_function:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addUpEchoAndReturn=create_function('$a,$b','$c=$a+$b;echo "$a+$b=$c<hr />";return $c;');
    }
    public function add_up_and_echo($a,$b,$c,$d)
    {
        $fn=$this->addUpEchoAndReturn;
        return $fn($fn($a, $b),$fn($c, $d));
    }
}


$x=new A();
$result=$x->add_up_and_echo(3,4,5,25);
echo "<hr /><hr />Final Result: $result";
?>
```